# Drawing numerical ray

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Maybe i am seearching wrong but I couldn't find way to draw this ray with vertical lines. How?

Comment: Number line is probably the word you had been looking for.

Answer (score 6):

There are many possibilities to draw this, here is one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
\foreach \X in {0,...,13}
{\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1);}
\foreach \X in {0,4,10,12}
{\node[anchor=north] at (\X,-0.1){\X};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Something that allows you to add numbers with commas as decimal separators is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
\foreach \X in {0,...,13}
{\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1);}
\foreach \X in {0,2.6,4,6.7,10,12}
{\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1)
node[below] {\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\X}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have denser ticks, try e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(10*(\X-int(\X)))}] in {0,0.1,...,13}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\draw (\X,0.15) -- (\X,-0.15);
\else
\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1);
\fi}
\foreach[evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(10*(\X-int(\X)))}] \X in {0,2.6,4,6.7,10,12}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\node[anchor=north] at (\X,-0.15){\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\X}};
\else
\node[anchor=north] at (\X,-0.1){\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\X}};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, it is also possible to add the ticks with non-integer values above the ray.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0);
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(10*(\X-int(\X)))}] in {0,0.1,...,13}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\draw (\X,0.15) -- (\X,-0.15);
\else
\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1);
\fi}
\foreach[evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(10*(\X-int(\X)))}] \X in {0,2.6,4,6.7,10,12}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\node[anchor=north] at (\X,-0.15){\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\X}};
\else
\node[anchor=south] at (\X,0.1){\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\X}};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to change the parameters in \foreach with floating numbers but it's a mess. Is there a solution?

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Can you please tell me what you tried precisely? (I am very confident that there will be a solution.)

Comment: I need to draw this: https://imgur.com/a/d3w9Q9i The size number can be the same. Hope you can read it.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov I added two more examples.

Comment: Here what happens. https://imgur.com/a/0SvfMTw
Is there any way to make the numbers with floating point over the ray?

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Sure. I added something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(15,1)
\psaxes[yAxis=false](0,0)(-1,-1)(15,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The zero is intentionally left hidden for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

With simple LaTeX commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\unitlength=1cm
\begin{picture}(14,0.5)(0,-0.5)
\put(0,0){\vector(1,0){14}}\multiput(0,-0.1)(1,0){14}{\line(0,1){0.2}}
\put(0,-0.5){0}\put(4,-0.5){4}\put(10,-0.5){10}\put(12,-0.5){12}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.25,-0.5)(14,0.25)
\psaxes[yAxis=false,labels=none,arrows=->](14,0)
\foreach \X in {0,4,10,12}{\uput{8pt}[-90](\X,0){$\X$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]